# How to prevent the tab key to start over from top when fill a form?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, drop-down-menu, usability

I am just wondering how to prevent the tab key to start over from top when using only the keyboard to fill a form such as a dropdown menu.

I am using bootstrap for this form and want due to usability reasons to jump to the next input field or dropdown menu instead of start over again from the top when tab on an item in a dropdown menu.

Try it on yourself:

[Bootstrap form](http://andalusi.com/development/)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `<element tabindex="1">` folllowed by `<element tabindex="2">`and it will follow the order you want. But at this time atleast on your form its working fine for me in chrome.

Comment: It works only until you select one item from the dropdown menu. After that you have to start from the top because the tab key jumps to the first item on the page => the navbar.